# Excel - how to return a date in same row as the last data entered as text in another column

Tags: excel-formula

Query is how to write a formula in a different worksheet cell to return the last date from Col A for a "Y" found in Col G...in the example 10/6/17 would be returned.  I have seen that INDEX and LOOKUP can be used but examples are for numbers rather than text so not sure how to adapt.

[image]

Comment: When you say last, do you mean the bottom-most row or the most recent date?

Comment: Had a chance to try out the answers? How'd you get on? If they resolved your issue please take a moment to mark the answer as accepted... Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that was great - the Index version was the one I was after and solved my query....I will investigate the MAX version too.  Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

***This will work for the most recent date***

**`=MAX(IF($G$1:$G$32="Y",$A$1:$A$32,""))`**

This is an Array formula and will need to be entered by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

This formula builds an array using the If statement. `IF([ColumnG]="Y"` then put the value of [ColumnA] in the array otherwise place a blank value.

We then ask for the `MAX()` value from this array to be returned.

Please note that array formulas can really slow down your work so it is good practice to use exact ranges rather than whole columns.

***This will work for the bottom-most row***

Also an Array formula:
`=INDEX(A1:A32,SMALL(IF(G1:G32="Y",ROW(G1:G32)),COUNTIF(G1:G32,"Y")))`

[image]